# Is it possible to freeze nuts to keep them from going bad?

Tags: freezing, nuts

For convenience, I like to keep a variety of nuts on hand for cooking and baking. Is it possible to freeze nuts to keep them from going bad?  Walnuts, Almonds, Pecans in particular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have all three kinds in my freezer at this moment. Although all of mine are raw, if you usually use toasted nuts, you can toast them first, then freeze. Saves a step later when cooking.

Answer (score 8):

Yes.

(do I need more of an answer than that?)

Okay -- the issue is the fats going rancid, and cold will help slow the process, but you should also try to get as much air out as possible.

Answer (score 1):

I freeze raw nuts but I put them in an oxygen-impermeable glass jar with a rubber gasket glass lid that clamps shut. I use the same kind of container for raw nuts I keep in the cupboard.

Comment: Freezer flavors might otherwise cause problems.